# Oracle PL/SQL Stored procedure returns null for a parameter defined as SELECT TO_CHAR(date, format)

Tags: .net, database, oracle, plsql

I have to access the following stored procedure from .NET:

```
 FUNCTION get_date (param_id NUMBER, 
                    param_date OUT VARCHAR2)

     RETURN NUMBER IS

 BEGIN

     SELECT TO_CHAR(date_stored, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
     INTO param_date
     FROM MYTABLE
     WHERE storage_id = param_id

     RETURN 0;

 EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         RETURN -1;
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RETURN SQLCODE;

 END get_date;
```

I try to connect with the following code:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();                    
                    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
                    command.BindByName = true;
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = "GET_DATE";
                    OracleParameter paramScheduleId = command.Parameters.Add("param_id", OracleDbType.Int32);
                    paramScheduleId.Value = id;
                    OracleParameter paramDate = command.Parameters.Add("param_date", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                    paramDate.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;                    
                    OracleParameter retVal = command.Parameters.Add("retVal", OracleDbType.Int32);
                    retVal.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                    OracleDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                    var date = ((OracleString)paramDate.Value).Value,                    
                }
                catch (OracleException e)
                {                    
                    throw e;
                }
            }
```

The table has a valid date. But the parameter param_date is always null.

Calling the procedure from Java code works.

To identify the problem I tried with a parameter of type Date and a simple SELECT SYSDATE INTO param_date FROM dual; and it works.

But with a parameter of type Varchar2 and SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') INTO param_date FROM dual; it doesn't.

I think it has something to do with TO_CHAR function or the format...

Comment: I don't know .net. However, I'd expect the same function to run the same result regardless where it is called from. Are you **sure** you're conected to the same database? Did you pass the same PARAM_ID value? Did you check that row with that value actually exists in the table? What does the function return (NUMBER value)? Not related to your problem, but: I don't like the way you're doing it. Function is supposed to return a *single value*, accept IN parameters but - don't use OUT ones in functions. If you need that, consider using a stored procedure instead of a function.

Comment: I don't know .Net, but it's not a stored procedure, it's a stored function. Possibly a procedure is what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a stored procedure, it's a stored function. Also, you're trying to call it using ExecuteReader, which wouldn't be used if it were a stored procedure

Either:

- change it to be a stored procedure rather than a function and
- change your c# to use `ExecuteNonQuery()`

Or:

- change it so it doesn't use OUT variables (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/parameter_declaration.htm#CJADCJFE cautions against them),
- change the c# so it's a `SELECT get_date(:pwhatever) FROM dual` and
- call `ExecuteScalar()` to get the value rather than needing return values

Don't forget to close your connection